# Listview have black backgroud when using ProgressBar in every listview item (Android > 3.0)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Please help me with this problem.
I am using a progress bar in every item in ListView(for lazy loading).
It work well in Android 2.2.3 but when I run the app in Android 4.1.1 or Android 3.2 I face on a problem.Please see my attachment :
[image]

Please look on "red" rectangle. The background is black. It happen when I scroll the listview.
And I don't do much thing in getView method (ArrayAdapter, just show text).
If I set the progress bar Visible = Gone. The list view work well.

Have you ever faced on same problem or have solution please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  may also set listview Property `android:scrollingCache="false"` ,and `cacheColorHint` to `transparent`.

Answer (score 2):

set the listview cacheColorHint to transparent.

Comment: I tried it. But it is not work. I did like this : listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: Oh. I fixed it follow your comment. But set cacheColorHint to White ( not Transparent). Thank for your help  Changwei Yao